# How to create zero or one to many relationship using sql

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, database-design, relationship

I have this [data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsmaF.png) generated by EntityFramework in an existing application but i want to create the same tables with the same relationships in my database.

I succeeded creating the relationship (**one to zero or one**) between **Student** and **StudentAddress** with the following query which is correct:

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
StudentId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName VARCHAR(30),
LastName VARCHAR(30),
City VARCHAR(30),
State1 VARCHAR(30),
StandardId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Standard(StandardId));

CREATE TABLE StudentAddress(
StudentId INT,
Adress1 VARCHAR(30),
Adress2 VARCHAR(30),
City VARCHAR(30),
State VARCHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT StudentAdress_PK PRIMARY KEY(StudentId),
CONSTRAINT StudentAdress_Student_FK FOREIGN KEY(StudentId) 
REFERENCES Student(StudentId));
```

My question is considering this [data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsmaF.png) how to create the relationship (**zero or one to many**) between **Standard** and **Student** tables.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What does "write zero or one to many relationship query between Standard and Student tables for example" mean?

Comment: In fact i want to create the relationship between **Standard** and **Students** tables. When you take a look at this [data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsmaF.png) you will notice that the relationship between both tables is **zero or one to many**

Comment: So, make Student.StandardId nullable?

Comment: You can generate a database create script from an EDMX. Or create a database from DbContext.Database.

Comment: Yes David Browne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this the same way that you implemented the one to zero or one relationship.

So far you have a foreign key in `StudentAddress` to `Student`.  There is nothing enforcing one address per student.  (You could do so with a unique index on `StudentAddress.StudentId'.)

So do the same thing.  Have a `StandardId` field in the `Student` table, and you will have a many Student to zero or one Standard relationship.

Comment: Notice that the combination of primary and foreign key constraints on StudentId (at the end of the StudentAddress table declaration) is enforcing one address per student.

Comment: Thank you @MarlinPierce, i already had `StandardId` field in `Student` but it was marked as `not null`. I just removed the key word `not null` and  it perfectly worked!

Comment: @GerdWagner is right. I expected the primary key on the StudentAddress table to be something other than the foreign key, like StudentAddressId.

Comment: I understand your point @GerdWagner but in this case there is no obligation to have one address per student. When you look at the [data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsmaF.png)  you will notice that `StudentAddress` has `StudentId ` as `PK` and `FK`. What i did is only the reproduce this data model in my DB. I used to ask myself if a `PK` can be null in SQL; this example is clearly giving me the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need a third table that stores the relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE StandardStudenRelation (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , StandardID INT NOT NULL
    , StudentID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT Student_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY(StudentId) 
        REFERENCES Standard(StudentId)  
    , CONSTRAINT Standard_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY(StandardID) 
        REFERENCES Standard(StandardId) 
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Russel but it seems like you did not get my point. Please look at this [data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsmaF.png) , i want to create the relationship between **Standard** and **Student** tables. I'm looking for the right query to do that.

Comment: Same answer, though: edited to show third relationship table between Student and Standard.